# Swig std::vector<std::string> C++ to R fails

Tags: c++, r, string, vector, swig

I am using Swig 3.0.8 under Ubuntu 16.04 (g++ 5.4) and the following minimal example fails :

TestStrVec.h

```
#include <iostream>
void display_str(std::vector<std::string> vec)
{
  for(auto str: vec)
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

teststrvec.i

```
%module rteststrvec

%include <std_string.i>
%include <std_vector.i>
%template(VectorString) std::vector<std::string>;
%include TestStrVec.h
%{
  #include "TestStrVec.h"
%}
```

I swig/compile like that (csh)

```
swig -c++ -r -o teststrvec_wrap.cpp teststrvec.i
g++ -std=c++11 -fpic -shared teststrvec_wrap.cpp -I/usr/share/R/include -L. -o rteststrvec.so
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH .
```

Then I test in R

```
source("rteststrvec.R")
dyn.load("rteststrvec.so")
display_str(c("a", "b", "c")) # ERROR: SEGV in swig::asptr
```

The same example replacing std::string by double everywhere works perfectly.
Could you please help to fix the problem?

Comment: My bad. I forgot the module name in teststrvec.i.
Sorry. Original post edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice update about this question: Swig 4.0.1 currently fixes the issue!